# What is the easiest way to get a list of all my content (urls) with pageviews?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to get a list of all urls on my site ordered by the number of visits/pageviews they get. But I don't want to just see them like I do through Google Analytics what I need is to be able to get them to show on a page on my site, so that later I can retrieve the first ten or modify them.

My site uses wordpress. I hope there is an easy way to do it cause it doesn't seem to be something "big" enough to hire somebody but I'll be forced to do it if I can't. Anyway thanks

Comment: Do you have access to apache access log ? Is your site on share-servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install a web stats plugin for WordPress, like [Blog Stats for WordPress](http://www.w3counter.com/resources/wordpress-plugin). Just go to the plugins page in your wp-admin and use the search bar there. Then you can have a list of most popular pages in your wp-admin.

Answer (score 0):

You could examine source of this plugin and its method of retrieving url: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-sitemap-generator/ it generates xml sitemaps.

I thing You will need to add some tables to databse, this tutorial shows how do this to get popular posts by views: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/intermediate-wp-plugins-most-popular-by-views/,

If You merge methods I thing You will get what You want.

Answer (score 0):

It might be more involved than what you are looking for. You might have better luck with Quantcast because I know for certain they have some basic summaries that you can just cut and paste on your site. Google has much more powerful tools however, and they have the Data Export API which you can use to integrate the analytics data into your site. http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/home.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm using statpresscn http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/statpresscn/